# Error when publishing Spring application to Geronimo web server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, geronimo

I'm trying to set up Spring with Geronimo web server, but I'm getting the following error:

```
2010-10-08 18:52:45,105 WARN  [PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver] Cannot search for matching files underneath URL [bundle://316.0:1/com/unveiled/politics/] because it does not correspond to a directory in the file system
java.io.FileNotFoundException: URL [bundle://316.0:1/com/unveiled/politics/] cannot be resolved to absolute file path because it does not reside in the file system: bundle://316.0:1/com/unveiled/politics/
 at org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils.getFile(ResourceUtils.java:204)
 at org.springframework.core.io.AbstractFileResolvingResource.getFile(AbstractFileResolvingResource.java:51)
 at org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource.getFile(UrlResource.java:168)
...
```

This application seems to work on JBoss AS.

Some other configuration files that matter:

Web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- Handles all requests into the application -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/app-config.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

app-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.unveiled.politics" />

    <!-- Configures Spring MVC -->
    <import resource="mvc-config.xml" />

</beans>
```

mvc-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

WelcomeController.java:

```
package com.unveiled.politics.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Controller
public class WelcomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value="welcome", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getWelcomePage(ModelMap model) {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Component-scanning will only work if the application (whether it's an EAR or a WAR) is unpacked by the application on to the filesystem. Appservers generally will do this anyway, for runtime performance reasons.

So it looks like your Geronimo server isn't doing this. Hopefully there's a setting somewhere where you can configure to unpack the app before running it.